# Not getting a variable name using class instance: Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am following an old tutorial about LiveData and ViewModel.These are the links.

1. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7UxPYxgBoA][1]
2. [https://resocoder.com/2018/09/07/mvvm-on-android-crash-course-kotlin-android-architecture-components/]

I am getting an error in InjectUtil.kt class while initiating FakeDatabase class and getting it's variable. I am following the tutorial and do not know why I am getting it.

```
//InjectUtil Object
package dk.humma.livedata_viewmodel.utilities

import dk.humma.livedata_viewmodel.data.FakeDataBase
import dk.humma.livedata_viewmodel.data.QuotesRepository
import dk.humma.livedata_viewmodel.ui.quotes.QuotesViewModelFactory

// Finally a singleton which doesn't need anything passed to the constructor
object InjectorUtils {
    // This will be called from QuotesActivity
    fun provideQuotesViewModelFactory(): QuotesViewModelFactory {
        // The whole dependency tree is constructed right here, in one place
        val quoteRepository = QuotesRepository.getInstance(FakeDataBase.getInstance().quoteDao) 
        //Getting error while trying to get quoteDao variable
        // Not accessing quoteDao
        return QuotesViewModelFactory(quoteRepository)
    }
}

//FakeDataBase class
package dk.humma.livedata_viewmodel.data

class FakeDataBase private constructor(){

    var quoteDao = DataTable()
    private set

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance : FakeDataBase? = null

        fun getInstance() {
            instance?: synchronized(this){
                instance?: FakeDataBase().also { instance = it }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it a compile error or a runtime error? If it's a runtime error/exception, post the whole stack trace.

Comment: please post the error to resolve the issue.

Comment: Here it is not accessing the quoteDao variable.         val quoteRepository = QuotesRepository.getInstance(FakeDataBase.getInstance().quoteDao) //I am not getting quoteDao. I just write here but in IDE it says, Unresolved reference: quoteDao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getInstance` function isn't returning anything - if you look at the documentation popup for the function, it'll have a return type of `Unit`. And `Unit` doesn't have a `quoteDao` property, which is why the IDE is complaining. If you ever get an error like that, check the type of the variable you're trying to access it on

You can fix it by either adding `return` (and adding the type when it complains)

```
fun getInstance() : FakeDataBase {
    return instance?: synchronized(this){
        instance?: FakeDataBase().also { instance = it }
    }
}
```

or as an expression (`=` instead of a function block, which needs a `return`)

```
fun getInstance() = instance?: synchronized(this) {
    instance?: FakeDataBase().also { instance = it }
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting another error in InjectUtils Object. Error is ''Change paremeter 'quoteRespiratory' type of primary constructor class 'QuotesViewModelFactory' to 'unit'. "

Comment: I can't see the class, but I'm guessing you need to do the same thing for ``QuotesRepository.getInstance()`` - it's complaining that the result of that call (``quoteRepository``, which you're passing into the ``QuotesViewModelFactory`` constructor) is of type ``Unit``. Which means ``getInstance`` is returning ``Unit`` (which is the "no return type" actual return type in Kotlin). You're probably just not returning the instance again